# print fails to print a list with appropriate index numbers after an ifelse statement

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns and I want to print a column based on a condition defined in an ifelse function. Sometimes the index numbers vanish making two entries on the same line.

Structure of the data:

```
A tibble: 5 x 2
  `open_pre_What do you think are the positive points of this course?` `open_pre_What do you think are the negative point…
  <chr>                                                                <chr>                                              
1 good summary, great room for questions,                              the course was not enough structured, it was very …
2 The course was very clear.                                           The teaching in the first day was, maybe, a few sl…
3 *ability to get clear about the basics                               *course structure visible for participants  *more …
4 Very clear                                                           The first day was a little bit slow!               
5 the raised topis were interesting                                    no structure, no agenda, no overview in the begini…
```

Reproducible data

```
structure(list(`open_pre_What do you think are the positive points of this course?` = c("good summary, great room for questions,", 
"The course was very clear.", "*ability to get clear about the basics", 
"Very clear", "the raised topis were interesting"), `open_pre_What do you think are the negative points of this course, and if applicable, what improvements would you suggest?` = c("the course was not enough structured, it was very easy to get lost,", 
"The teaching in the first day was, maybe, a few slow!", "*course structure visible for participants  *more connection to the advanced stats course", 
"The first day was a little bit slow!", "no structure, no agenda, no overview in the begining about the course content, too many questions to the class, no time to let contents sink in"
)), .Names = c("open_pre_What do you think are the positive points of this course?", 
"open_pre_What do you think are the negative points of this course, and if applicable, what improvements would you suggest?"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

the ifelse function returns the string "no comments" if the list is empty otherwise returns the first columns of the data frame

```
positive_comments = ifelse(identical(my_data[[1]], character(0))==TRUE,"No Comments",(my_data[1]))
positive_comments = unlist(positive_comments) #just to remove the column index 
print(positive_comments)
```

Output:

```
[1] "good summary, great room for questions," "The course was very clear."             
[3] "*ability to get clear about the basics"  "Very clear"                             
[5] "the raised topis were interesting"
```

Desired output:

```
[1] "good summary, great room for questions," 
[2]"The course was very clear."             
[3] "*ability to get clear about the basics"  
[4]"Very clear"                             
[5] "the raised topis were interesting"
```

EDIT:

transforming it in a data frame seems not to help.

```
positive_comments = as.data.frame(positive_comments)
print(positve_comments)

 c..good.summary..great.room.for.questions.....The.course.was.very.clear....
1                                     good summary, great room for questions,
2                                                  The course was very clear.
3                                      *ability to get clear about the basics
4                                                                  Very clear
5                                           the raised topis were interesting

print(positve_comments[[1]])
[1] good summary, great room for questions, The course was very clear.              *ability to get clear about the basics 
[4] Very clear                              the raised topis were interesting      
5 Levels: *ability to get clear about the basics good summary, great room for questions, ... Very clear
```

EDIT 2:

Removing the column name manually DO NOT resolve the problem in markdown

```
positive_comments = ifelse(identical(my_data[[1]], character(0))==TRUE,"No Comments",(my_data[1]))
positive_comments = as.data.frame(positive)
colnames(positive_comments) <- ""
print(positive_comments)
1 good summary, great room for questions,
2              The course was very clear.
3  *ability to get clear about the basics
4                              Very clear
5       the raised topis were interesting
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `print.default` only adds index numbers larger than 1 after (necessary) line breaks. That is not related to `ifelse`. Why do you care about how this is printed to the console? Alternatives depend on your specific requirements.

Comment: if i print the column before the ifelse condition it returns the index numbering correctly. i need to embed this in an automated markdown latex file so i need that every comment is displayed on a column

Comment: Make it a one column data.frame and print that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print.simple.list(positive_comments)`

Comment: this works but i need to print just the [1] and not [1, ] and the column index, any idea?

Comment: The `positive_comments` you have is a vector which does not have any column index. You can create a `data.frame`, give a column index and print it.